How to add declarativeNetRequest rule dynamically for certain (select)tabs opened from a particular site
I have a product that opens 3rd party customer sites using window.open in an additional window.(For doing some WSIWYG type editing on the site). I need to remove a few headers (eg Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) for tabs opened with our site in order for site to open and work like I need it to.(For this I utilise extension)
In MV2 it was easy as we would maintain an array of myProductTabs, when I open a new tab append tabId in myProductTabs. and in webRequest.onHeadersReceived I would check if current request is coming from one of the tabs in myProductTabs using details.tabId and then remove header right there.
But in MV3 the issues is the first time new tab is opened using window.open  I have to now add a new declarative netrequest rule where tabs property will be myProductTabs as new tab is added to array. (Remove old rule ofc).
Now this doesn't work . Probably because registering a new rule doesn't immediately add the rule and by the time its in effect main document has loaded.
If I refresh the tab , then it would work as rule has already been set.
Now I can set the rule to all tabs by default but that would be a security risk for the user. So is there any other way to do it?
Note: Im using updateSessionRules(Dont think using updateDynamicRules would help.Correct me if I'm wrong).

Before the request for new URL is made the tab is reported, so it looks like there's enough time:
const myProductTabs = {};
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(t => {
  if (!t.url && !t.pendingUrl && t.openerTabId in myProductTabs) {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules({
      removeRuleIds: [1],
      addRules: [{
        id: 1,
        condition: {
          tabIds: [t.id],
        },
        action: {
          type: 'modifyHeaders',
          responseHeaders: [
            {operation: 'remove', header: 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy'},
          ],
        },
      }],
    });
  }
});

Note that the service worker must be already running, otherwise it'll take more than 50ms to start it and the request will be already made. You can keep it alive forcefully.

are you sure this works on a newly opened tab. It doesn't seem to work for me. I've made sure there are no issues in my code. I've tried removing all conditions and applied rules to all tabs regardless of URL.

I've tested it in Chrome using open('https://example.com') and Set-Cookie header as I didn't have a site that sets COOP. Maybe this header requires adding requestMethods:['options'] or something else. Start by making sure you can remove this header in all tabs.
